# Difference between MATLAB's matrix notations

Tags: matlab, matrix

How do you read the following [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB) codes?

## #1

```
K>> [p,d]=eig(A)                     // Not sure about the syntax.

p =

    0.5257   -0.8507
   -0.8507   -0.5257


d =                               // Why do you get a matrix?

    0.3820         0                  
         0    2.6180
```

## #2

```
K>> p,d=eig(A)                  // Not sure about the syntax.

p =

    0.5257   -0.8507
   -0.8507   -0.5257


d =                                       // Why do you get a vector?

    0.3820
    2.6180
```

where

```
A =

     2     1
     1     1
```

Comment: You seem to be getting confused with Lua notation.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In your second case `p,d=eig(A)` [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB) is merely printing the previously calculated value of p from case 1 and then running the command `d=eig(A)`.

Before running case 2 try

```
>> clear p d
```

If you then run `p,d=eig(A)` it will return an error saying that p is undefined function or variable.

From `help eig`:

```
E = EIG(X) is a vector containing the eigenvalues of a square
matrix X.

[V,D] = EIG(X) produces a diagonal matrix D of eigenvalues and a
full matrix V whose columns are the corresponding eigenvectors so
that X*V = V*D.
```

Note there is no `V,D = EIG(X)` option. MATLAB functions that return more than one value will group them using the format:

```
[ ] = function()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
p,d=eig(A)
```

is the same as

```
p
d=eig(A)
```